# Follow a user in a Facebook group

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups

In an active Facebook group, with sometimes hundreds of messages per day, I want to be able to follow specific users. I know how to see all the group posts by a user, but ideally, I want to be notified of new posts, or see them in my news feed.